# deny public access to a folder but still accessible from other php files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I was wondering what is the best way you would deny public access to a folder, but other files on the server can access it?

For example, my templates and scripts I've paid for

```
 public/template/header.html
 public/template/paidscript.js
```

I don't want anyone to access files inside of template folder, but

```
 public/folder/index.php
```

and the index.php can have this code inside

```
<?php include (../tempalte/header.html);
include (../tempalte/paidscript.js);  ?>
```

and any other files on the server can access it.

Comment: In other words, no (except the index.php) one can _download_ `paidscript.js`, or let's say _view_ its content? If so, follow @hakre advice ..

Comment: Keep you `paidscript`s secret. Don't let them being executed by others. Take care.

Comment: If you're apache you can use htaccess and mod rewrite

Comment: If it's Javascript, nothing you can do will prevent a dedicated attacker from acquiring it.

Comment: Attacker? Well actually I think Matt paid for these scripts for a reason. He is just not so clear about how much he would like to allow, right?

Comment: @WaleedKhan, just change the word _attacker_ to _person_ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep some files secret, it's really a totally *bad idea* to place these files into a publicly accessible webroot. Place those files into a private directory on the server and you're fine.

You can access files in a private directory from any PHP script you like. Just specify the correct path to the file and you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, One level below the docroot - end of story!

Comment: Not all hosts allow that. More often there is a private folder or something similiar. But the general idea sounds fair.

Comment: @hakre Yes, I agree, but I wouldn't choose a host on that basis. Oh for experience. :)

Comment: Well it actually it can be a good sign if the hosts do not allow anything below the webroot directly.

Comment: @hakre Oh come now - and restrict you on how many other fronts... Shared hosting nirvana? :)

Comment: I have the feeling you misread my comment. All fine and dandy. No nirvana at all.

Comment: @hakre No misread/offence meant. Apologies if such conveyed. Wrong place for chat. Mia culpa.